# How to print the optimal path from beginning in dynamic programming technique

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Below is the code for standard maxsum of an array containing +ve and -ve numbers. I think, the below programs works correct. Bot how do I print the optimal path?
By keeping a pointer to optimal parent, I can print the path in backwards direction easily, but how to print it in forward direction, preferably without keeping too much extra bookkeeping.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int array[]={5,-5,3,4,-2};
    int n=5;
    int i;
    int maxsumendingat[n];
    int parent[n];
    int maxsum=-9999; // better way to code?
    int optimallastindex;

    maxsumendingat[0]=array[0];

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
       if(maxsumendingat[i-1] <= 0)

       { 
           maxsumendingat[i]=array[i]; 
           parent[i]=i; 
       }
      else
      { 
           maxsumendingat[i]=array[i]+maxsumendingat[i-1];  // also keep backtracking info
           parent[i]=i-1;
      }
    }

     // now print results
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
      if(maxsum < maxsumendingat[i]) 
      { 
         maxsum=maxsumendingat[i]; 
         optimallastindex=i;
      }
    }

    // now print path. how to print it in fwd direction?
    i=optimallastindex;
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
    while(parent[i]!= i)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[parent[i]]);
        i=parent[i];

    }

}
```

Comment: Asking how to get your code to work like you want it to is not on topic here. I have migrated this to Stack Overflow. Though it'd be fine if you post the finished code for a general code review once it does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the reversed path in a temporary array and then iterate that array backwards.

Comment: In other words, you could use a stack.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was wondering if I could do it without any additional space, but actually its not needed. It doesnt change space complexity. Because for a table of size O(n), printing path doesn't take more than O(n) space and for any table of space O(n^2), printing path wont take more than space O(n^2). So, I think we are fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can copy parents in new array (or stack) then iterate array in backward order, or instead of using parent use next and in your `else` statement do `next[i-1] = i`.